# Java: Regex pattern not working

Tags: java, regex

I have a file that I'm parsing that ALWAYS includes an email address. The file is currently laid out with a leading space before the `@` and we want to capture the domain.

```
foo @bar.com more data here
foo @foo.com more data here
```

We want to pull out `@bar.com` and `@foo.com` and I'm just starting to work with regex. I'm trying to pull the pattern "*@ at the start of a word boundary inclusive of all following characters up until the next word boundary*".

I've tried various iterations of the following, grouping things, square backets for the `@` literal...but nothing seems to work.

EDIT - actual code :

```
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.lang.*;
//
public class eadd
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String inputLine = "foo foofoo foo foo @bar.com foofoofoo foo foo foo";
        String eDomain = "";
       // parse eadd
        Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("(\\b@.*\\b)");
        Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(inputLine);
            if(m2.matches()) {
                eDomain = m2.group(1);
                } else {
                eDomain = "n/a";
            }
        System.out.println(p2+" "+m2+" "+eDomain);
    }
}
```

And the results when I run it.

```
(\b@.*\b) java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=(\b@.*\b) region=0,49 lastmatch=] n/a
```

All of my problems have been related to the what follows the `@` being searched as a literal instead of a pattern (e.g., looking for `.*` rather than `any and all characters`). I can't find references to `@` being a control character, so I don't think I need to escape out.

There are no similar examples in Oracle's java tutorials or documentation, SO, nor any of the online resources I checked out; I've been unable to find other samples of how people have handled this. Like I said, I'm fairly new with regex, but this looks to me like it should be working to me. What am I missing?

Comment: You must use `"\\b"` not `"\b"` -- which is a control character for backspace. The additional `\` is for escaping.

Comment: Veer is correct; you have to escape the escape character because both Java and regex use it to escape things.

Comment: @veer When I try that, it appears to be searching for a literal `(\b@.*\b)`...I'm printing `p2` to the console to see the pattern & my matcher isn't getting any hits.

Comment: `matches()` tries to match the _entire_ input against your regex - you're looking for a partial match and should use `find()`.

Comment: @JacobRaihle I must've missed that distinction in the tutorials. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java won't treat `@` as a word character - thus there is no word boundary at the start of your address. You could replace the word boundary with a simple whitespace match:

```
"\s(@.+?)\b"
```

(Or `"\\s(@.+?)\\b"` since this is Java) should do the trick. It looks for whitespace followed by `@` and matches until the next word boundary.

Edit: Oops, `.`, just like `@`, isn't a word character (duh). Use

```
"\\s(@.+?)(?:\\s|$)"
```

to match until the next whitespace or EOF. `(?:\\s|$)` is a non-capturing group that will match any whitespace or end of input.

Comment: for the first simple solution that fits the problem. if you KNOW that this is the format of emails you will be getting then why complicate?

Comment: @Eugene Right, domains are scary beasts but if they'll always be surrounded by whitespace it makes your life a lot easier :)

Comment: @Jacob OK. I get it. That makes a lot of sense! One quick clarification: Does regex (or java) require (@+wildcard) to be grouped separately from (wildcard-space at End) or is that just for better readability?

Comment: I separated the groups because you're not interested in the whitespace - this way only the domain itself is in a capturing group while the whitespace is ignored once the match has been confirmed. A capturing group is one you can access with `Matcher#group(int)` - putting `?:` at the start of a group makes it non-capturing.

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(@(?:[a-z][A-Z0-9_]+)\\.(?:[a-z][A-Z]+))");
```

This should work for you.

This regex starts looking for the @ . After that it looks for any word followed by the ".", followed by another word. For beeing familiar with the syntax you can take a look at [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Comment: Could you also explain what this regex is doing for the asker?

Comment: Don't you mean `[a-z][A-Z]` to match both upper and lower case?  Also, what about the other legal characters permitted in domain names?  Digits `[0-9]` ...

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Thanks, changed the pattern.

Comment: Personally I'd go with something less restrictive (as email addresses are notoriously loosely defined), more along the lines of `\\b@([^\\b]+)` (yes, I think you should even avoid requiring a full stop as I fully expect such email addresses to creep up with the new TLDs coming out).

Comment: hyphen is also permitted in urls

Comment: @Thor84no When I run your solution, `Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("\\b@([^\\b]+");` I get the following `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsup
ported escape sequence near index 7
\b@([^\b]+
       ^`

Answer (score 1):

try with this: `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\s)(@(?:bar|foo)\\.com\\b)");` 
or a general purpose pattern:
`"(?<=\\s)(@\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)+\\b)"`

Explain:
`(?<=\\s)`: look behind for match leading space before `@` 
`\\w`: match alphabet, digit, underscore
`\\b`: word boundary
`@\\w+(?:\\.\\w+)+`: match `@bar.com`, `@bar.com.au`, `@bar.com.xyz`, `@bar.foo.xx.yy.zz`

Comment: There really is no need to to use a look-behind, just let your desired result be a group and extract it that way.